# How to commit all version controlled files in svn

Tags: svn, wildcard, prefix

I have a couple of files under version control: `my_file.tex`, `my_ref.bib`, `Makefile` and a file not under version control: `my_file.pdf`.

All the version controlled files are modified, I tried the command `svn ci * -m "some message"`, but error `svn E200009: './my_file.pdf' is not under version control`.

I don't want the pdf file to be version controlled. Is there any simple command, other than commiting one by one, that could commit all the version controled files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do an

```
svn commit -m "Commit message"
```

Let subversion determine what to move.

Answer (score 0):

I use Tortoise SVN in Windows (which integrates SVN with Explorer), and I apologize that I'm not quite sure where "SVN native" capability ends and value added by Tortoise SVN starts, but it provides a very useful capability for just such a situation...

One can add specific files or folders to an "ignore list".

So, for example, with judicious application of this "ignore" capability, one can easily set up a development tree of source files to be kept under SVN control, yet never have to see any files in commit dialogs and such but those that are actually under Subversion control.  Things like build results can simply be excluded from SVN control.

-Noel